# Excercise dealing with subgroups of $\text{GL}_n(K)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$U_n=$$\left( \begin{array}{rrrr}
1 & * & \cdots & * \\
0 & \ddots & * & \vdots \\
\vdots & 0 & \ddots & * \\
0 & \cdots & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}\right) $$T_n=$$\left( \begin{array}{rrrr}
* & * & \cdots & * \\
0 & \ddots & * & \vdots \\
\vdots & 0 & \ddots & * \\
0 & \cdots & 0 & * \\
\end{array}\right) $$D_n=$
$\left( \begin{array}{rrrr}
* & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & \ddots & 0 & \vdots \\
\vdots & 0 & \ddots & 0 \\
0 & \cdots & 0 & * \\
\end{array}\right) $

$U_n,T_n,D_n$ are all sets which describe Matrices of the forms above. Furthermore they are all subsets of $\text{GL}_n(K)$. I have to Show that a Matrix $A$ of the set $T_n$ can be describes as a product of a Matrix $U_A$ from the set $U_n$ with another Matrix $D_A$ from the set $D_n$.

Is there a way to prove it by induction?

I have looked at the Problem for $n=2$

$\begin{pmatrix} 
*_{11} & *_{12}\\ 
0 & *_{22} \\   
\end{pmatrix} $
=$\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & *_{12}*_{22}^{-1}\\ 
0 & 1 \\   
\end{pmatrix} $$\begin{pmatrix} 
*_{11} & 0\\ 
0 & *_{22} \\   
\end{pmatrix} $

I know that I have to set the trace-elements of $D_A$ equal to the trace Elements of $A$.
And from my Observation my guess for the Elements which are not within the trace of $U_A$ (i.e. they are not $1$) is that they can be calculated **inductively** by the element in $A$ which is in the same Position as the element we want to calculate and the inverse of the element which is below the element we want to calculate.

How can I formalize this thought, and how can I then prove this property inductively. Would appreciate an Approach which does not make use of bloxmatrices.

Comment: do you know quotients of groups by subsets? I would use that, since as soon as you can proof that $D_n$ is a normal subgroup, you could just devide it out and be done, (respectively, you could do that either way, just a little less nice)

Comment: I have heard something About normal Groups we have defined them as subgroups of a Group where the left coset is Always equal to the Right coset. They create a Quotient set

Comment: yep, then just use that $D_n \subset T_n$, kill it, and proof that you can identify this with $U_n$
(and as you actually do not need a groupstructure on the quotient, you can ignore the reauirements on the cosets).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set $D_n := \text{diag}(T_n)$; that is, $D_n$ is the diagonal matrix consisting of the diagonal elements of $T_n$.  Then, since multiplying on the right scales the rows of a matrix, set the elements of $U_n$ to be the elements of $T_n$ with each row divided by the corresponding diagonal.  In other words, $(U_n)_{ij} = \frac{(T_n)_{ij}}{(D_n)_{ii}}$.